# When validation error occurs, I want to display the error value in the input form

Tags: forms, validation, cakephp, error-handling, cakephp-3.0

I would like to discuss the implementation method.
I am using CakePHP 3.8.5.

The procedure is shown below.

1. In the input form that allows you to enter only numbers,
   The status is displayed as “100”.

   - It is assumed that the validation logic is implemented in the Model class.
2. Change the content of the input form to "a",
   Press the "POST" (Submit) button.
3. Validation error occurs,
   The content of the input form is "100".

   - (Points to consult) I want to display here as "a".

The process of saving is
This is the flow of executing save () after patchEntity ().

I would appreciate any advice.
Thank you very much.

Comment: This is precisely the behaviour that you will get with standard Cake coding, per the tutorial or what you get if you use the Bake tool. If some part of it isn't working, you'll need to explain specifically what is wrong, and show us some relevant code.

Comment: Thank you very much. I review it.

Answer (score 0):

I understood the cause. 
It was because I was setting the "value" attribute. 
Thank you very much.